# How to kill Django Background Tasks?

Tags: django, background, task

I need to check if a payment is confirmed, so I can notify the user with an email. 
The payment token is valid for 24h.

My intention is to check every 5 minutes if the payment is confirmed using the repeat feature from `Django Background Tasks`

Now if the payment is confirmed I want to kill the task, because it becomes not only useless, it fills the database with completed tasks, and also takes processing power from server

Is there a way to remove a `Django Background Task`? 
or repeat until some event happens?

Celery is not an option.

Comment: use django beat schedular to set and remove the cron entry from db on success.

Comment: I can’t use Celery

Comment: You tried to [revoke the tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks) you would need the task_id